# Iterating over a list of strings, and appending all the strings to another, except the first word

Tags: python, string

I'm trying for some time to iterate over a list of strings and remove the first word of the string, by appending the remaining of the string to another list, here's what I wrote:

```
from sys import argv

my_file = argv[1]
output_list = []
count = 1

with open(my_file) as input_file:
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        while count < len(line.split(' '):
            ouput_list.append(line.split(' ')[count])
            count += 1
        count = 0

with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in output_list:
        output_file.write(line)
```

Everything seems in place, but I'm getting a syntax error... What Am I missing ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least tell us what syntax error you are getting.

Comment: you missed closing `len(line.split(' ')` close it, and you have other problems too in your rog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two syntax errors. First, there's a missing right parenthesis in this line:

```
while count < len(line.split(' '):
```

Second, you misspelled `output_list` in this line:

```
ouput_list.append(line.split(' ')[count])
```

Beyond that, your code seems to be logically flawed because it removes all the whitespace between the words.

If your goal is to remove the very first word of the file and the whitespace surrounding it, while leaving everything else intact, these two lines should do the trick:

```
text = open(my_file).read()
text = re.sub('^\s*\w+\s*', '', text)
```

It can also be written in one line, but I prefer two lines for clarity.

You'll need the `re` module, so your complete program would look like this:

```
import sys, re

my_file = sys.argv[1]

text = open(my_file).read()
text = re.sub('^\s*\w+\s*', '', text)

with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(text)
```

If you use this input file:

```
ant bear cat
dog elephant
```

You will get this output:

```
bear cat
dog elephant
```

I presume that's what you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

This is working code :-

```
from sys import argv

my_file = argv[1]
output_list = []
count = 1

with open(my_file) as input_file:
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        while count < len(line.split()):
            output_list.append(line.split()[count])
            count += 1
        count = 0

with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in output_list:
        output_file.write(line+'\n') # should write in new line
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful for the OP if you explained what you changed and why

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the consideration. @March0514S you missed closing parenthesis as i mentioned in comment `len(line.split())` and misnamed here `ouput_list.append` its `ouput_list`. you better use `split()` while splitting over spaces rather than `split(' ')` and insert the data in new line or with some space so do `output_file.write(line+'\n')` or `output_file.write(line+'\t')`